# Rulers and Grids relationships

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I know that a similar questions were asked, but I did not see any answer that solves the issue -

Can we reset the rulers to show us ticks values every 10 point and not those that can be divided by 6?

I failed to adjust rulers to grid no matter what I performed (double click in the left upper corner or zeroing via dragging to any desired point.

Sometimes I need the rulers and grid to match...

The main part of question - Can we match grid lines and rulers perfectly as grids are just continues of rulers ticks?

Illustrator CS6.
Any new solution? What I miss?

[image]

UPDATE after the answer by Scott - now it is near to be perfect

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using CM or MM for the rulers (a system divisible by 10)? Pixels or points will never be divisible by 10. Or change your grid to be divisible by 6.

Comment: @scott if we have no best solution, we have acceptable one: by your advice I converted units(Prefs->Units) to mm and set the Grid to every 2mm - on Retina it looks not perfect, but almost perfect alignment. Please, convert the comment to answer. I am sure - it is useful, because it gives a acceptable solution to the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the rulers to something metric, which is based on increments of 10, such as centimeters, millimeters, etc.

Or, alter your grid settings to be divisible by 6. Pixels (or points) will never divide well by 10 since they use increments of 6 as the base.
<sub>(Even though pixels technically have *no size*)</sub>