# How make rulers relate with grid somehow in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, grids, units

How to make rulers and grid show the same coordinates and units?

Currently it shows absolute delirium for me:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rulers and Grids relationships](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28343/rulers-and-grids-relationships)

Answer (score 3):

You either have (as you noted yourself) different units set for the grid and ruler, or the grid is set to repeat on a weird interval.

You can change the units of the ruler by right clicking on it. For the other settings, you have to look into the preference pane (`⌘+K` or `ctrl+K`). Units are obviously under the `Units` tab. Changing the grid is done under the `Guides & Grid` tab and then the setting `Gridline every:` where you can choose how often the grid repeats. The ruler repeats with a multiplier of 6 when using points or pixels, and 10 when using mm or cm, so to line them up you should do the same with the grid (and change the setting `Subdivisions` accordingly).